# Python syntax error in class definition

Tags: python

I am new to Python I got an error at class `def` line. I am not sure what mistake I have done. Please check it and let me know.

```
class contactservices():
    def GetDirectorySearchList(userId:int, searchKey,result:ContactResultSet):
    ret = RETURN_CODE.RECORD_NOT_EXISTS 
    cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
    rows =""
```

`invalid syntax (contactservices.py, line 15)`

Thanks in advance.

Full Code:

```
from django.db import connections
from api.enums  import RETURN_CODE
from api.user.contactmodel import ContactModel
from api.user.contactmodel import DirectoryModel
from api.user.resultset import ContactResultSet
from api.datalayer.dbservices import dbservices

class contactservices():

"""Get Directory Search of a specific user"""
def GetDirectorySearchList(userId:int, searchKey, result:ContactResultSet):
     ret = RETURN_CODE.RECORD_NOT_EXISTS
     cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
     rows =""
     try:     
        #user triple quote for multiline string.   
        msqlquery = """SELECT a.id, username, first_name, last_name, firm,email,extension, extpassword,start_date,expiry_date,status,presence_status
         ,aliasname,picturepath,statusupdatedate
        FROM  ocktopi_login a where (first_name LIKE '%%""" + str(searchKey) + "%%'  OR  last_name LIKE '%%" + str(searchKey) + "%%' OR aliasname LIKE '%%" + str(searchKey) + "%%') AND id NOT IN (select contact from usercontactmapping where user = """ + str(userId) + ") and id <> " + str(userId) + "";
        #cursor.execute(msqlquery)
        rows = dbservices.query_to_dicts(msqlquery)
        ret = RETURN_CODE.RECORD_EXISTS         
     except Exception as e:
         ret = RETURN_CODE.RECORD_ERROR         

     #We dont have a way to map with column name . So only solution is column index.Changed to dictory using a method now.
     directorylist = list()
     for row in rows:
        directory = DirectoryModel()
        directory.Id = row['id']
        directory.Username = row['username']
        directory.FirstName = row['first_name']
        directory.LastName = row['last_name']
        directory.Firm = row['firm']
        directory.Email = row['email']
        directory.Extension = row['extension']
        directory.Status = row['status']
        directory.PresenceStatus = row['presence_status']
        directory.AliasName = row['aliasname']
        directory.Picturepath = row['picturepath']
        directorylist.append(directory)

     result.ReturnCode = int(ret)
     return directorylist

"""Get Contact Details of a specific user"""
def GetContactList(userId:int, result:ContactResultSet):
     ret = RETURN_CODE.RECORD_NOT_EXISTS
     cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
     rows =""
     try:     
        #user triple quote for multiline string.   
        msqlquery = """SELECT a.id, username, first_name, last_name, firm,email,extension, extpassword,start_date,expiry_date,status,presence_status
         ,aliasname,picturepath,statusupdatedate
        FROM  ocktopi_login  a inner join usercontactmapping b on a.id=b.contact and a.id <> """ + str(userId) + " and b.user= " + str(userId) + "";
        rows = dbservices.query_to_dicts(msqlquery)
        ret = RETURN_CODE.RECORD_EXISTS         
     except Exception as e:
         ret = RETURN_CODE.RECORD_ERROR         

     #We dont have a way to map with column name . So only solution is column index.Changed to dictory using a method now.
     contactlist = list()
     for row in rows:
        contact = ContactModel()
        contact.Id = row['id']
        contact.Username = row['username']
        contact.FirstName = row['first_name']
        contact.LastName = row['last_name']
        contact.Firm = row['firm']
        contact.Email = row['email']
        contact.Extension = row['extension']
        contact.Status = row['status']
        contact.PresenceStatus = row['presence_status']
        contact.AliasName = row['aliasname']
        contact.Picturepath = row['picturepath']
        contactlist.append(contact)

     result.ReturnCode = int(ret)
     return contactlist

"""Add user contact"""
def AddUserContact(userId:int, contactId:int):
     ret = 0
     cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
     rows =""
     try:     
        msqlquery = """insert into usercontactmapping (user,contact) values(%s, %s)""";
        cursor.execute(msqlquery,(userId, contactId))
        ret = cursor.rowcount
        return ret      
     except Exception as e:
         ret = -1
     finally:
         cursor.close()
     return ret 

"""Remove user contact"""
def RemoveUserContact(userId:int, contactId:int):
     ret = 0
     cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
     rows =""
     try:     
        msqlquery = """delete from usercontactmapping where user=%s and contact=%s""";
        cursor.execute(msqlquery,(userId, contactId))
        ret = cursor.rowcount
        return ret      
     except Exception as e:
         ret = -1
     finally:
         cursor.close()
     return ret
```

Comment: I believe it is indentation issue

Comment: it could be indentation or the type hint.Which python version and what is the error

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: show full class code?

Comment: 2.7  python version

Comment: See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) about type hints. They are not valid in Python 2.7. Unrelated but why do you have all the docstrings _above_ your functions rather than underneath `def`?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run Python 3 code on Python 2. This isn't a good idea. If you can't upgrade to Python 3, you should try to find a Python 2 version of that code.

Comment: If you can't do either of those things, you're likely to encounter additional problems. BTW, in Python 2 `class contactservices():` should be `class contactservices(object):`, otherwise you get an old-style class instead of a new-style class. An old-style class may work ok in this script, but there are some new-style things that it cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def GetDirectorySearchList(userId, searchKey,result):
     ret = RETURN_CODE.RECORD_NOT_EXISTS 

     cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
     rows = ""
```

Annotations such as `userId:int` don't work in Python 2.7. 
Also make sure the code is indented properly.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with annotations.

Comment: @vaultah in comments, OP says Python 2.7. Throwing syntax error for me, isn't it in the latest versions of Py 3.x?

Comment: @roganjosh yeah, right. My bad, should have read the comments first.

Comment: @DrevanTonder please re-phrase the answer. It is not `type declaration` it is `type hint`.There is a lot of difference

Comment: @Sarathsp Technically, it's not even a type hint; it's a function annotation (as now stated in the answer), for which type hints are just one use. It's still legal (though possibly discouraged now) to use values other than `mypy`-style type values.

Comment: After reading many articles issue resolved by upgrading my python from 2.7 to 3.5